# Extract the number from a string in PHP

Tags: php, extract

How can I extract the number 12345 from the following string in PHP ?

```
<span id="jordan934" itemprop="distance"><span class='WebDistance'>#$@20B9;&nbsp;</span>12345</span></h3>
```

I was using the following until that '#$@20B9' string was not in it .

```
 $results = $dom->query('#jordan934"]');
        $distance = false;
        if (count($results)) {
$distance = (int)trim($results->current()->textContent);
}
        return $distance;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regular expression

```
$str = 'jordan934';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Please tell me what to edit in the following line to get that 12345 number out of the above string :

$distance = (int)trim($results->current()->textContent);

Comment: try this
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $results->current()->textContent, $matches);  $distance = $matches[0][0];

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dom object

```
<?php
$html = '<span id="jordan934" itemprop="distance"><span class=\'WebDistance\'>#$@20B9;&nbsp;</span>12345</span></h3>';
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($filePath);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="my-class";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
var_dump($nodes);
```

Answer (score -1):

Other not widely known function is:

```
$str = 'jordan934';
$int = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

http://php.net/manual/pl/function.filter-var.php